# Git folder content (probably submodule) can't be commited

Tags: git, commit, git-submodules

I've got a drupal project with composer. With one of the drupal modules, the module "entity_embed" came along. As I tried to commit it, it would not commit the contents of the folder, resulting in a BitBucket view like so:

[image: BitBucket showing folder entity_browser as submodule]

I figured out that this seems to be a submodule. Because I don't have any tools on my webserver (not even composer), i need a clean repository to commit, without any deploy mechanisms. So I tried to add the files manually, but this won't work (no output, same behavior).

I also tried to go to the directory and execute

```
git add entity_embed/*
```

But this resulted in the error message

```
fatal: Pathspec 'entity_embed/composer.json' is in submodule 'docroot/modules/contrib/entity_embed'
```

As I'm not familiar with submodules, I have no Idea what to do. Best way would be something to achieve that the files in the folder are just regular files which can be commited.

I could not find any `.gitmodule` file in my whole project...

**UPDATE**

For those in need of an immediate, quick-and-dirty solution, i found out which drupal module in my case required these modules, so I removed them from the module's composer.json files and downloaded & copied them manually. This does the job at the moment for my project which does not ignore vendor files (I always check in all the files in my project).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this problem is that the submodules contain a hidden folder called `.git`. Delete this folder and you will be able to commit the modules as is.

There are two strategies out there: Commit your vendor, or don't commit it. If you commit it, you have to ensure no other .git directories are contained in it.